# Characterization of $L^2$ convergence by $E(\cdot),V(\cdot)$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to show that, given a sequence of random variables $\{T_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, we have:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}\left[|T_n-c|^2\right]=0\iff
\lim_n\mathbb{E}(T_n)=c, \lim_n V(T_n)=0
$$
I managed to show $(\Leftarrow)$, but I'm stuck on $(\Rightarrow)$. Can anyone give me some *hints*?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: ${\Bbb E}\left[(T_n-c)^2\right] = V(T_n) +(c-\mu_n)^2$, where $\mu_n ={\Bbb E}(T_n)$.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that too!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use Jensen's inequality to show $\mathbb E|T_n-c|\to0$. Then you have just one more thing to prove...

Comment: I'm having some trouble showing that $E|T_n-c|\to 0\Rightarrow E(T_n)=c$.

Comment: Triangle inequality / Jensen's inequality / whatever you want to call it. $|\mathbb E X-\mathbb E Y|\le\mathbb E|X-Y|$.